# How do I know when I can multiply by something on an inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

My doubt: How do I know when I can multiply by something on an inequality? and by this I don't mean multiplying by numbers as 3 or -3, I mean multiplying by things like x or $\ln(x)$ or $\cos(x)$, etc. functions in terms of x basically. I know I shouldn't be multiplying in a inequality on both sides like $\frac{x^2+3}{x-1}>0$ by $x-1$ because we don't know what x is and it might be negative while we don't know, hence why the recommendation of not multiplying by x. But came to a limit the other day which was $$\lim_{x\to 0}x\cos(\frac{1}{x})$$ and they did : $-1\leq \cos(\frac{1}{x})\leq 1$ and they proceeded to *multiply by x* on an inequality? or double inequality? and I was really extranged because this conflicted with my idea of not multiplying by x or whatever function of x on an inequality. Specifically they did $-x\leq x\cos(\frac{1}{x})\leq x$ and then they limit'd the 3 and by the squeeze theorem, blah blah blah, the limit is 0. But I only used this anecdote with the limit to clarify my doubt, the same way I'd like the reason to this, I'd love to know when I can multiply by something and when not on an inequality.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, you have to reverse the sense of the inequality when you multiply by something negative.  If you are going to multiply by an expression, you need to determine whether the expression always has the same sign or not.  If it always has the same sign, you can go ahead and reverse the inequality or not as required.  If not, you need to split into cases based on the sign of what you are multiplying by.

Your example is very special because of the symmetry.  You start with $-1 \le \cos \left(\frac 1x \right) \le 1$.  You are guaranteed that $x \neq 0$ because you divide by it already.  If $x \gt 0,$ you can multiply through by it to get $-x \le x\cos \left(\frac 1x \right) \le x$.  If $x \le 0$ you need to reverse the signs of the inequality and you get $x \le x\cos \left(\frac 1x \right) \le -x$.  The only change is the position of the negative sign on $x$ on the ends.

Comment: oh so we did consider the change but because of the plugging 0 from the limit, -0 is the same as 0, so we don't consider both results? ish? not fully sure. And apart from this I may ask that I've read something about functions being monotonically increasing or something like that, if they are monotonically increasing, we can multiply both sides by that thing, is this true? ie can you explain this fact and why it works if it's not much to ask?

Answer (score 0):

When you have the inequation $f(x)\leqslant g(x)$ for $x\in I$, then you can multiply both side by $h(x)$ (without inversing the $\leqslant$) only for the $x$ such that $h(x)\geqslant0$.

So you must distinguish 2 cases if $h(x)$ is not always positive.

But in your example ($-1\leqslant \cos \frac{1}{x} \leqslant 1$), the two cases lead to the same inequation since $-(-1) = 1$, so if you're not specifically working on inequalities, you can go faster and not distinguish the 2 cases.

Comment: In the example, we do need to distinguish the two cases because the upper limit changes from $x$ to $-x$, whichever is positive, and the lower limit is similar.