# How do I know when I can do something to both sides in an inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

This question is basically derived from one that I asked previously but with a different focus, that's why I chose not to just edit the question. Please let me know if I should've. The previous question: [How do I know when I can multiply by something on an inequality?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3963579/839549)

I ask about a **general** rule about when to do something to both sides in an inequality, because saying "whenever the thing you are multiplying is negative, flip it" isn't complete as we can for example, log on both sides, sqrt both sides, raise to 5 both sides, etc. I have also been told that this has something to do with being monotonically increasing or not? Not sure, but it somewhat rings a bell on this topic. I'd love to be given some insight, I know I can't multiply by negative numbers, or if I want to, I have to separate into cases. But I'd love to be given some insight of everything I've mentioned on this post

Comment: It depends on that something, but common sense goes a long way.

Comment: A "monotonically increasing" condition is almost certainly circular, in that you need to know that the inequality is preserved to know that the associated function is monotonically increasing.

Comment: If you want to go from $a \leq b$ to $f(a) \leq f(b)$ this absolutely requires function- and potentially also value-specific inquiry into $f$, $a$, and $b$ (sometimes it is simpler than that, but it is not always simpler than that). There are some commonly used general principles, but almost nothing at a high level of generality.

Comment: can I be given some examples? for example, as in how do I know that **only** for $a>1$, $\log_a(x)>b\implies x>a^b$ is true?

Comment: No shortcut to developing your common sense by stretching your intuition by attacking 100 pertinent problems, having a teacher/tutor check for mistakes, and learning from your mistakes.  If it was easy, anyone could do it.  The less math talent that you were born with, the harder you have to work to achieve the same result.

Comment: [There is no royal road to mathematics.](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Euclid)

Comment: okay I get it, can someone answer my question on the comment?

Comment: @Xetrez : If $a<1$, then $a^p<a^q$ means that $p>q$, as a number smaller than $1$ raised to a larger power will actually decrease in size. In your case, $$\log_a(x)>b$$ which is the same thing as $$\log_a(x)>\log_a a^b$$ so if $a<1$ then in fact you'd have $a^b>x$. Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use intuition to know whether an inequality manipulation is valid. For example, it is easy to see that adding $2$ to both sides of $a \gt b$ makes $a+2 \gt b+2$ true. However, if you multiply both sides by $-1$, $-a  \gt -b$ is FALSE. This is because negative numbers with big magnitudes, like $-7$ are smaller than negative numbers with smaller magnitudes, like $-2$, thus if you negate both sides of an inequality, the side with the bigger magnitude side becomes smaller.

However, you can also use rigorous math, as well, to see when an inequality manipuation is valid. If a function $f(x)$ is increasing for all $x$, then $f(a) > f(b)$ if $a \gt b$, which you can see intuitively. So, if we want to see if adding $2$ to both sides of an inequality preserves the inequality, we can let $f(x) = x+2$. From the graph of this, we can tell $f(x) = x+2$ is increasing, thus if $a \gt b$, then $f(a) = a+2 \gt f(b) = b+2$ or $a+2 \gt b+2$. However, a function like $f(x) = -x$ is decreasing for all $x$, which you can tell from the graph, thus $f(a) < f(b)$ if $a \gt b$. Thus, if we have $a \gt b$, we have $f(a) = -a < f(b) = -b$ or $-a \lt -b$.

See if you can apply similar logic on inequality manipulations like taking the reciprocal of both sides, or the absolute value.

Comment: sorry about the delayed answer, I didn't see this. Thank you very much this is what I was looking for, though there's something still wondering in my head, what would $f$ be on this step? Is $f$ the $f(x)=\log_2(x)$? $$2^x>2^{2x-1}\implies x>2x-1$$

Comment: yes, you're right, what do you think the graph of log2x behaves like?

Comment: great, and yeah it's increasing for all $x$ in the domain, so i guess it doesn't change the sign. Let me be sure I understand the concept with functions that aren't increasing on all the domain, can't think of any functions right now of those right now where you can do $a>b\implies f(a)>f(b)$, but how will it change if it's not increasing in all the domain? ----------- And another question, **separate** from the one I just asked, say I have $2^x>3^x$, if I multiply both sides by $x\sqrt{e^x}$ for example, as this is not increasing in all the domain, would we have to separate into 2 cases?

Comment: For functions that are increasing/decreasing on separate cases like $|x|$, you split it into cases. We have $|x|$ increasing for x>0 and decreasing for x<0, thus if a>b and a,b positive, then we have |a| > |b|, otherwise if a>b and a,b negative, we have |a| < |b|. If we have a is positive and b is negative, there actually is no clear cut answer because we can have 2 > -1 and |2| > |-1| and 2 > -3 and 2 < |-3|.